# How to email exception logs at the end of robot run

Tags: email, exception, logging, kofax, kapow

Email logs only if there was an exception at any point in the run.
I only want this for a specific robot, not all robots under management console.
I know there is an option under management console, but that emails for every robot and every log.I don't want that. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a try step as the very first action of your robot. At the lower branch, add any action to log your error (write file, send email):

[image: try]

Configure each action that may fail as follows:

[image: error handling]

The special robot property `Robot.executionErros` will hold the relevant error message. Here's an example:

[image: expression configuration]

That being said, I would rather rely on Kofax RPA's logging capabilities - any error gets logged to the logging database. You can then use another robot to get those entries and email send messages. This allows you to use a single robot for sending out email notifications instead of adding above steps to each one of them.

Comment: Yes you are right, it is better to use another robot for this purpose. Thank you for the help!